# Web Scraping - Why are these numbers interpreted as strings?

Tags: import, string-manipulation, number-representation

I started with:

```
data = Import["https://www.destatis.de/DE/ZahlenFakten/GesellschaftStaat/Gesundheit/Todesursachen/Tabellen/Sterbefaelle_Unfaelle.html", "Data"]
```

Then extracted the data I needed with:

```
alter01b = data[[3,3, 4, 1, 2]]
alter02b = data[[3,3, 4, 2, 2]]
alter03b = data[[3,3, 4, 3, 2]]
alter04b = data[[3,3, 4, 4, 2]]
alter05b = data[[3,3, 4, 5, 2]]
alter06b = data[[3,3, 4, 6, 2]]
alter07b = data[[3,3, 4, 7, 2]]
alter08b = data[[3,3, 4, 8, 2]]
alter09b = data[[3,3, 4, 9, 2]]
alter10b = data[[3,3, 4, 10, 2]]
alter11b = data[[3,3, 4, 11, 2]]
```

And it gave me this:

21
67
86
706
800
800
1 394
1 787
2 436
6 727
9 738

The numbers with a whitespace (1 394 and onwards) are not regarded as such even when I remove the whitespace.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please try `If[StringQ[#], FromDigits[StringDelete[#, WhitespaceCharacter]], #] & /@ 
data[[3, 3, 4, All, 2]]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ReplaceAll[
 data[[3, 3, 4, All, 2]],
 s_String :> FromDigits[StringDelete[s, " "]]
]
```

> {21, 67, 86, 706, 800, 800, 1394, 1787, 2436, 6727, 9783}

The `ReplaceAll` can of course also be represented as `data[[3, 3, 4, All, 2]] /. s_String :> FromDigits[StringDelete[s, " "]]`, if preferred.

Comment: It´s working! Thanks a lot. Started with Wolfram Language only a couple of days ago...

Comment: @user63323 Glad to help!